# .htaccess on a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

long story short:

This is my (sub-) domain and file:

`https://sub.domain.com/test.php`

And I would love to have it like:

`https://sub.domain.com/test`

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^test/?$ test.php [NC,L]
```

But I always get a 404 not found.

The strange part: When I change `^test/?$` to `^test/test/?$` and try to get to `https://sub.domain.com/test/test.php` everything works fine.

I have no idea what to do, I searched like a maniac -- maybe someone has a solution?

(btw the subdomain points to a different directory than domain.com; so there are no nested folders like `sub.domain.com` -> `domain.com/sub`)

Thanks :)

Edit: Server is running Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Comment: your `.htaccess` needs to be in `sub` folder and the `.htaccess` in the parent folder may affect the behavior.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't change anything unfortunately. But I found a (temporary) solution. The server seems to have an issue with rules that have the same name. `^test/?$ test.php [NC,L]` won't work, but `^anothernameforthetest/?$ test.php [NC,L]` will.